# A new instance of ViewController generated every time

Tags: ios

I have an audio player in a `ViewController`. I call this `ViewController` when a song is selected in the `DidSelectRow` of a `tableview` in another `viewcontroller` called the `AlbumViewController`.The problem I face is when i select a song ,it pushes to audioplayer view controller and starts playing ,but when i press back and select another song from the album ,the previous song is not stopped ,it still plays while the new song is selected.Now the newly selected song pushes to another instance of audio player `viewcontroller` and plays . Whereas the previously selected song also plays along with it  . And for each selection of song ,a new instance of audio player `viewcontroller` is pushed ,and all the selected songs are played together. My album controller which has the `tableview` with it's did select row code is as below

```
 viewContObj=[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];  //viewcontroller=audio player controller
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewContObj animated:YES];
   viewContObj.url =[NSURL URLWithString:albumURLstring];
  [viewContObj playLiveStream:nil];
```

and the audio player play method is as below.

```
   -(IBAction)playLiveStream:(id)sender

{ if ( ![streamer isPlaying] )

{   [self createStreamer];
    [self setButtonImageNamed:@"loadingbutton.png"];
    [streamer start];
}
else
{   [self setButtonImageNamed:@"play.png"];
    [streamer pause];
}}
```

Comment: Just stop your audio player on didselect before passing the url and play in viewWillAppear of your audio play view. I hope it'll work.. :)

Comment: You mean to call the playlivestream method in ViewWillAppear method of Audio player controller class? like this -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    
    [self playLiveStream:nil];
}

Comment: Yes. and stop player on didselect. B.T.W. which player you are using to play audio?

Comment: what is the result now? have you tried it?

Comment: Instead of alloc and init all the time you tap the row just create one ivar and keep it alloc init in viewDidLoad method and just assign the url property and push it on navigation controller

Comment: @Panu_Parekh am using matt's audio streamer . the prob is it calls new viewcontroller each time i select a song .

Comment: @Wolvorin Can u explain if possible!

Comment: sure and sorry for the delay I am not able to visit the SO these days frequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put one ivar in .m file's `@interface` part like this

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *playerView;
```

And in `viewDidLoad` method alloc init it as below

```
playerView=[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
```

And in `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method do as below

```
playerView.url =[NSURL URLWithString:albumURLstring];
[playerView playLiveStream:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:playerView animated:YES];
```

May this solve your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Use singletone instance for ViewController and try like this

creating singletone instance in ViewController

```
    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
        {
            self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
            if (self) {
                // Custom initialization
            }
            return self;
        }

//1. Customize singletone 

        -(id)initWithCustomDetails:(NSString *)customDetails
        {
            self = [super init];
            if(_sharedMySingleton)
            {
                [_sharedMySingleton.view removeFromSuperview];
                _sharedMySingleton = nil;
            }
            _sharedMySingleton = self;

            return self;
        }

2. exact singletone method for creating instance

 +(ViewController *) getViewControllerInstance
{
    @synchronized([ViewController class])
    {
        if (!_sharedMySingleton)
        {
            _sharedMySingleton = [[self alloc] init];

        }
        return _sharedMySingleton;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

While creating instance use

1. viewContObj=[[ViewController alloc]initWithCustomDetails:@"details"];

instead of this method

```
viewContObj=[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
```

//Exact singletone instance creation

1. viewContObj = [ViewController getViewControllerInstance];

and try..

Answer (score 0):

Add release after pushing

```
viewContObj=[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];  
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewContObj animated:YES];
viewContObj.url =[NSURL URLWithString:albumURLstring];
[viewContObj playLiveStream:nil];
[viewContObj release];
```

And in ViewController.m:

```
- (void)dealloc{
    [streamer stop];
    [streamer release];
    [super dealloc]; 
}
```

Ok?

Comment: this is an arc program . so i don't use dealloc !